# Modular Forms - Valance Formula Proof - Truncation height question- integrating boundary of fundamental domain

Tags: modular-arithmetic, problem-solving, modular-forms

In the proof of the valence formula you integrate $f'(t)/f(t)$ around the boundary of the fundamental domain, with some modifications such as :

- omitting the points $i, \omega $
- since equivalence is allowed on the boundary, modifying as needed to ensure such points that are equivalent only occur once in the interior
- truncating the fundamental domain at some finite height, rather than letting it run up to $\infty$, let this finite height be called $T$

My question:

My notes say that all poles and zeros of $f$ must lie below some finite $T$, if this were not the case $f$ would not be meromorphic about $\infty$

I don't understand this comment at all. So the fundamental domain is a sketch over $t$ and not its associated variable $q=e^{2\pi i t}$, and for the definition of meromorphic at $\infty$ (that is meromorphic at $q \to 0 $ ) I have :

The expansion about $q=0$ is:

$ \sum\limits_{n>>\infty} a_n q^n $

i.e. as long as the pole at infinity is not of infinite order, otherwise it is a essential pole (I think is the term).

I'm struggling to see the connection to the requirement of a truncation height? The only thing that is needed is that the pole at $\infty$ is of finite order?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The singularities of a holomorphic function on a domain $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ must be isolated, they cannot cluster otherwise the function would not be well defined.

In your case, $f$ is meromorphic on the upper half plane (or on the punctured disk if you prefer) so its singularities there cannot cluster. If you had poles over any height $T$, then you would have a sequence of poles converging to infinity (or to $0$ in the punctured disk). This is impossible because infinity would be a cluster point for the poles, which is a contradiction. This argument works regardless of the behaviour of $f$ at infinity.

A similar reasoning holds for the zeros: if you had zeros over any height $T$, then you would have a sequence of zeros converging to infinity, which is impossible unless $f$ is identically zero (by the identity principle).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How is it though that you are guaranteeing existence of construction of such a sequence, since the space above T is not closed? ( I have only, to be honest, seen similar proofs in closed spaces were Bolzano-Weierstrass  is used to construct a sequence.) Also my thoughts are along this: S is used to map infinity to zero but zero is not in the fundamental domain. so are we not also preventing having any zeros or poles at infinity in this modified F?

Comment: There is no need to give an explicit sequence. The argument is as follows: suppose $f$ has poles over any height and let $T_n$ be a strictly increasing sequence of heights. Then for every $n$ you get a point $a_n$ above $T_n$ which is a pole for $f$. The sequence $\{ a_n \}$ necessarily converges to infinity because it eventually goes above any given height. Therefore infinity is a cluster point for the poles of $f$, which is prohibited (because $f$ is meromorphic at infinity).

As for the second part, since you are working with level one all the cusps are identified.

Comment: Hi I follow your proof and agree that all cusps are identified, however we have a lot of modular forms that have a pole at infinity right... but you say for a meromorphic function it must be that no poles lie above a certain height. E.g. Consider a holomorphic function on H but meromorphic only due to a simple pole at infinity. Now infinity and zero are equivalent so this is true, however...I'm getting confused with the fact we are integrating over the ' fundamental domain' , which ofc is not unique, and does not include zero, however this has nothing to do with the previous point ?